# CSS table for responsive design, but text lower then image

Tags: html, css

I changed all table, tr and td tags for responsibility to div definitions:

```
    /* responsive table */
    .table {
        display: table;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border: 1px;
    }

    .table-row {
        display: table-row;
        min-width: 15em;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .table-cell:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
    .table-cell:nth-child(2) { background: green; }
    .table-cell:nth-child(3) { background: blue; }
    .table-cell:nth-child(4) { background: yellow; }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 655px) {
        body {
            display: block;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .table { display: block;}
        .table-row {display: block; }
        .table-cell {display: block; }
    }
```

HTML implementations:

```
    <div class="table products_cart">
        <div class="table-row table-row-bottom-line">
            <div class="table-cell image_cart">
                <img src="./image-text-responce_files/1_26_zoom.jpg" alt="Bild zum Artikel 1.26 Gegenverkehr">
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                    <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</b><p>
                    Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet doner meatball jowl short ribs, chicken prosciutto salami frankfurter. Pig drumstick turducken short ribs, brisket meatloaf ham hock shankle andouille corned beef strip steak. Venison ham bresaola strip steak. Pork belly ribeye prosciutto t-bone
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                    Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet doner meatball jowl short ribs, chicken prosciutto salami frankfurter. Pig drumstick turducken short ribs, brisket meatloaf ham hock shankle andouille corned beef strip steak. Venison ham bresaola strip steak. Pork belly ribeye prosciutto t-bone
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell" id="">
                173.59
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My problem: my image pushes all the text part to the level of the lower border from the image (first image). I tried with flow and something like this. no success.

I should have all on the top line as text parts do (second image)

[image: Wrong alignment]
[image: Desired alignment]

Comment: use `.table-cell{vertical-align:top}`

Comment: Yes, that's it. thx